# Using str and int indexing in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Is it possible to use string and integer for array indexing in python?

For example:

```
i = 0
for id in list_2:
    list_1[i]['First'] = list_2[id]['First']
    list_2[i]['Second'] = list_2[id]['Second']
    i = i + 1
```

**EDIT 1:**

**list_2** is dictionary containing ids and set of values for each ids. For example:

```
{1000: {'iscrowd': 0, 'image_id': 438346, 'category_id': 1}, 1001 : {'iscrowd': 0, 'image_id': 438345, 'category_id': 2}}
```

**1000** and **1001** are the ids.

Comment: What are `list_1` and `list_2` here?

Comment: List_2 is a dictionary, for example :{0001: {'iscrowd': 0, 'image_id': 438346, 'category_id': 1}, 0002: {'iscrowd': 0, 'image_id': 438346, 'category_id': 1}}. 0001 and 0002 are the ids.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Lists can be indexed by ints:

```
myList = ['a', 5, 435, -5, "a string", "another string", 80]
index = 4
myList[index]
```

But lists can't be indexed by strings. However, dictionaries can be indexed by key, which can be a string:

```
myDict = {"First": 42, "Second": 89}
key = "First"
myDict[key]
```